# Golang send Gmail mail with attachment returns Invalid multipart

Tags: go, gmail-api

I am trying to send an email with the Gmail API. It works when I use Postman but I am unable to get it to work in Golang. Hope someone can help me out. My code below:

```
url := "https://gmail.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?uploadType=multipart"
    method := "POST"

    payload := generatePayload(form.Value["to"][0])
    content := generateRawEncodedContent(form)
    payload = strings.Replace(payload, "{{RAW_MESSAGE}}", base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(content)), -1)

    client := &http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, strings.NewReader(payload))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    req.Header.Set("Authorization", "Bearer "+accessToken)
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "multipart/related; boundary=your_boundary")

    res, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    defer res.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(body))
```

**This returns an error:** Invalid multipart request with 0 mime parts.

My payload:

```
--your_boundary
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
    "payload": {
        "headers": {
            "To": "john@doe.com"
        },
    },
    "raw": "{{RAW_MESSAGE}}"
}

--your_boundary
Content-Type: message/rfc822


--your_boundary--
```

And the RAW_MESSAGE will contain a base64 encoded (**base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString**) payload like the one below:

```
From: John Doe <john@doe.com> 
To: John Doe <john@doe.com> 
Subject: Trying to send mail with attachment
Date: Wed, 24 Mar 2021 17:27:06 -0000 
Message-ID: <1234@local.machine.example>
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="your_boundary"

--your_boundary
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

This will be some HTML or plain text content

--your_boundary

--your_boundary--
```

All the values are correct and the body is filled with plain text. So personally I would say everything payload wise is good.

I do the exact same in Postman and then it is working perfectly, but when trying to do it in Go I am unable to get it working.

Hope someone can help me out.

EDIT:

I did what mkopriva suggested and the output is the exact same as the one in my Postman. Below is the output from this line of code:

```
url := "https://gmail.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?uploadType=multipart"
method := "POST"
payload := generatePayload(form.Value["to"][0])
payload = strings.Replace(payload, "{{RAW_MESSAGE}}", base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(content)), -1)

client := &http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, strings.NewReader(payload))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    req.Header.Set("Authorization", "Bearer "+accessToken)
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "multipart/related; boundary=your_boundary")

    res, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
```

Output:

```
sending multi part email
POST /upload/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?uploadType=multipart HTTP/1.1
Host: gmail.googleapis.com
User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1
Content-Length: 840
Authorization: Bearer xxxxx
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=your_boundary
Accept-Encoding: gzip

--your_boundary
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
        "payload": {
                "headers": {
                        "To": "xxxx@xxxx.xxx"
                },
        },
        "raw": "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
dXJfYm91bmRhcnktLQ=="
}

--your_boundary
Content-Type: message/rfc822


--your_boundary--
```

When I look at Postman it shows me this:

```
    POST /upload/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?uploadType=multipart HTTP/1.1
    Authorization: Bearer xxx
    Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=your_boundary
    User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.10
    Accept: */*
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Host: gmail.googleapis.com
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Length: 821
    --your_boundary
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
    {
    "payload": {
    "headers": {
    "To": "xxx@xxx.xxx"
    },
    },
    "raw": "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
dXJfYm91bmRhcnktLQ=="
    }
    --your_boundary
    Content-Type: message/rfc822
    --your_boundary--
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    X-GUploader-UploadID: ABg5-UyF8gE4raq8iR_ouN-4_DrmdrIsd6PczBm-UknQse1Osst_fOSVijKwh6JW4OTOHp9ldBO1Z6LyKDPAsBdVL2GExjxoUA
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
    Vary: Origin
    Vary: X-Origin
    Vary: Referer
    Content-Length: 97
    Date: Tue, 30 Mar 2021 16:51:17 GMT
    Server: UploadServer
    Alt-Svc: h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
    {
    "id": "178840bed75072f5",
    "threadId": "178840bed75072f5",
    "labelIds": [
    "SENT"
    ]
    }
```

which is exactly the same as I have. Yet I receive an error:

> Malformed multipart body.

The way I build my body for the request at the moment is shown below.

```
func generatePayload (recipient string) string {
    return `--your_boundary
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
    
{
    "payload": {
        "headers": {
            "To": "`+recipient+`"
        },
    },
    "raw": "{{RAW_MESSAGE}}"
}

--your_boundary
Content-Type: message/rfc822


--your_boundary--`
}
```

I then replace {{RAW_MESSAGE}} by this line of code:

```
payload = strings.Replace(payload, "{{RAW_MESSAGE}}", "base_64_encoded_string", -1)
```

Comment: Before you do `client.Do(req)` take a look at the complete request with [`dump, := httputil.DumpRequestOut(req, true)`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#DumpRequestOut) and then `fmt.Println(string(dump))`, compare the output of that to the postman request and look for significant differences, if you can't find any please share the dump output with us here by updating the question.

Comment: I edited my message :)

Comment: Include the HTTP headers in the question from both the request dump and the postman request (and try to make the postman request more readable so that differences, if there are any, can easily be spotted). The correct HTTP headers are necessary for an HTTP request to succeed.

Comment: Since this is how Postman gives it, I was thinking I shouldn't modify it that's why I didn't make it more readable sorry. Maybe it has something to do with indenting or so?

Comment: It's a bit all over the place. Please include the full dump, headers and body, *together*. See example here: https://play.golang.org/p/HiC68K90JnH very simple and clear. Don't remove anything from the dump, not even the method and url, unless it's sensitive data that cannot be shared in which case you can overwrite it with Xs or something. And try to put the postman dump in the same format as the Go dump as much as possible, don't remove anything and cross out the only stuff that's secret.

Comment: And show the plain *raw* HTTP request that postman is actually sending, do *not* show the example Go code that postman generated for you.

Comment: With postman you can get the raw HTTP request by going to the postman console, then finding and clicking on the relevant request, and finally clicking on the "show raw log" link on the far right. https://imgur.com/wkvNLCR (note the raw log shows the request and response together, copy only the request, i.e. up to the end of the body).

Comment: Yeah, didnt know how to get it sorry -- think I got it now! thanks so much for your patients!

Comment: The Go dump is good now, all we need is the proper postman dump, the raw request.

Comment: The only thing I see is that the broken Go version has greater Content-Length than the Postman version, it could be that the Go version has some whitespace characters that are considered invalid by the multipart/related spec. In the Go code that you're using to generate the json, try generating it without the indentation and new lines. For example if you're using [`json.MarshalIndent`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#MarshalIndent) then switch to [`json.Marshal`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal).

Comment: Also that newline inside the json's "raw" string looks suspicious. Both dumps have `RnJvb....gotLXlv`<NL>`dXJfYm91bmRhcnktLQ==`, that doesn't look right, try to remove it and see if that helps. You can use the `httputil.DumpRequestOut` in your Go code to confirm that you've truly removed that new line.

Comment: There is no new line in it, I double checked it and it is just one long code without any newlines (enters) or any other weird things in it.

Comment: Got it working!!! ill post the solution later, thanks for all your help and patients mkopriva!!!

Comment: What happens if you smush the json part into a single line in the `generatePayload` function? e.g. https://play.golang.org/p/M5CgYyv5BJf

Comment: Ok, I'm glad you got it working.